# Trying to understand LINQ method notation

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to understand LINQ method notations better.

Say I have a DataTable:

```
DataTable table = new DataTable("Products");
            table.Columns.Add("ProductID", typeof(int));
            table.Columns.Add("ProductName", typeof(string));
            table.Columns.Add("Category", typeof(string));
            table.Columns.Add("UnitPrice", typeof(decimal));
            table.Columns.Add("UnitsInStock", typeof(int));
```

Assume that variable products is being loaded from the DataTable("Products")

```
var products = testDS.Tables["Products"].AsEnumerable();
```

So I know I can do queries like:

```
var productNameGroups = words4.GroupBy(x => x.Field<string>("ProductName").Substring(0, 1)).Select(x => new { FirstLetter = x.Key, Words = x});

var productGroups = products.GroupBy(p => p.Field<string>("Category")).Select(x => new { Category = x.Key, Products = x });
```

I'm having trouble grasping the x.Key in the Select method.  I'm not sure how its set or when I can/cant use it.

Comment: x is an enumerator like in a foreach loop : foreach(x in testDs.Tables["Products"].Rows())

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `x.Key` is specific to processing results of a `GroupBy` method.

When you do this

```
var res = someData.GroupBy(item => item.Property);
```

the result is an `IEnumerable` of `IGrouping<K,V>` - key/value pairs, where the `Key` property represents the value of `Property` on which the items are grouped.

Since in your case the grouping is done on the string representing the first letter of `ProductName` or `ProductCategory`, that is what you get when you reference `x.Key` in each of the groups returned by the query.